# Stream.iterate() does not work as expected?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

What is wrong with the code below:

```
public class StreamFactoryMethodExample {

    static UnaryOperator<Integer> uOp = p1-> p1 + p1;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream.iterate(1, uOp).forEach(System.out::println);
    }   
}
```

Its output is an infinite number of zeros:

```
0
0
0
....
0
```

what I expect instead is an increasing arithmetic progression: 2, 4, 6, ...

This works with the implementation below, but not with the implementation above:

```
        Stream.iterate(0, p1->p1 + 1).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Why?

Comment: It does not. It's just printing the numbers too fast for your eyes to see when 1,2,4,8, 16 (which is by the way what you should expect, not 1,2,3,4...). The 0,0,0 you're seeing happen after the integer overflow has occurred. Try adding `.limit(10)` before `forEach`, you'll see the output.

Comment: @ernest_k Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: @JohnKugelman I close-voted this. I see it as not reproducible as the code is indeed working as expected - except of course that the code should print a geometric progression whereas OP expects an arithmetic one :-)

Comment: But it is reproducible and it's not a typo. The question shouldn't be closed.

Comment: @JohnKugelman - please correct me if I'm misunderstanding that close reason. The OP's problem *"Its output is an infinite number of zeros"* is simply not possible to recreate. The output is not made of just zeros.

Comment: @ernest_k If you ran the program, didn't get any 0's, and couldn't even understand what the OP was even referring to, that would be "not reproducible". The fact that you understood the post and saw what the OP missed means it's a fine question that should be left open.

Comment: If it said "Its output *appears to be* an infinite number of zeros" instead of "is" the question would stay open, right? Let's not ding the OP for slightly imprecise wording.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine. Just limit the output to exclude unexpected output. You see `0` because after `31st` element you value is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`:

```
UnaryOperator<Integer> uOp = val -> val + val;
Stream.iterate(1, uOp).limit(31).forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
2048
4096
8192
16384
32768
65536
131072
262144
524288
1048576
2097152
4194304
8388608
16777216
33554432
67108864
134217728
268435456
536870912
1073741824
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like ernest_k said in the comment, try:

```
Stream.iterate(1, uOp).limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);
```

And if you want a bigger number, change the `Integer` to `Long`.